# Polynomial approximation of a function in a chosen interval

Tags: polynomials, approximation, approximation-theory

I don't know if this should be in the math forum or the computer science one, but I think it is more relevant in the math section.

I would like to approximate nonlinear functions typically used in neural networks on a given interval. However, the Taylor polynomial approximations are in a neighborhood of a point, leading to overflows in my computations. What's more, I don't think Taylor polynomials are the best ones to used, due to the degree required to fit "well" the function to approximate.

Do you have other algorithms than Chebyshev / Taylor polynomials to approximate functions, that might be faster / more accurate to fit a given function in an interval [a;b]?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are given a number of data points on the polynomial you want to approximate, interpolation would probably work best. Or at least, it's the first to come to mind.

Comment: Did you think about Padé approximants ? Could you provide a function and a interval ?

Comment: It's for neural networks, so basically the activation functions are either sigmoid or tanh, and as an interval we could take [-8,8] for example.. hmmm Padé approximants don't give you polynomial solutions, and I need polynomials as they are only defined in term of additions and multiplications